# Stop amazon ec2 health checker from checking a file

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a php file in my amazon webserver which runs a bulk email script which sends around 50 emails to the employees in my company, i have set up a cron task to run the php file every monday morning but it seems that this file gets triggered automatically, looking at the access logs im pretty sure its due to amazons health checker, is there a way to force it to ignore my file? or if there is a php/linux method that can do something.

Thanks

Comment: What makes you think it is coming from "amazons health checker"? What does the log contain?

Answer (score 3):

Amazon's health checks access a URL of your choosing.

Pick a specific URL that doesn't trigger your scheduled task.

Answer (score 0):

"Amazon" does not run any health checkers.

However, you can configure health check capabilities in a few services such as **Amazon Route 53** and **Elastic Load Balancing**. If you are using either of these services, check their configuration and confirm it is using the desired Health Check URL to test your application.